# Adding to a hash table without overwriting

Tags: c, hashtable

Here is the problem I'm having:

I'm able to echo the last variable that is set, but not previous variables.
So if x=Welcome and I do echo $x... I get Welcome.
But if I do xx=Back... it erases the original x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing the pointers in your table, but the pointers are to a local variable which is simply reused… you're overwriting your key and value that the table point to.

In your Node structure, make copies of what the pointers point to so that you keep a copy that won't get overwritten.

Since you're dealing with strings, an easy way to solve this is to replace (in Table_add):

```
p->key = key;
p->value = value;
```

with

```
p->key = strdup(key);
p->value = strdup(value);
```

but if you do this, you need to be sure to `free()` both values prior to freeing a Node.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! So by freeing both values, do I just do free(key) and free(value) prior to doing free(p).